# Opening a webpart from a separate page in modal form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am an IT schoolboy who is on an 8 month apprenticeship. I have been charged with creating a little sharepoint site for our tiny group in the company I am working at. I have site collection (is that the correct term?) permissions, and no access to SP Designer. Everything I have done so far is via webparts (lots of CEWP).

I built a wiki site, and a few other things. I was then asked to build an image carousel with jquery. Done.

Now my current issue.

I have a list of applications we support in our department. It has about 14 columns, 10 of which are custom. I figured out a way to dynamically build a list and link them to another publishing page, on which I build a little thing to give a custom table of the output.

All of this works just fine.

However, now I would like it so the user clicks on the link, and the table (from the CEWP on the publishing page) opens in a sort of lightbox style effect. Actually, at this point, any modal fashion.

I have no experience with ajax, and am pretty new at a lot of this stuff. I am in no way asking for anyone to write my code and do my job, but would appreciate some pointers as in what direction I should point my research? I don't want to waste days 'barking up the wrong tree'.

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks.

EDIT - I'm working in SP2007. From what I understand, modal dialog is not supported in 2007?

EDIT2 - If anyone else happens upon this......  I ended up using jquery ui dialog widget. Worked like a charm.  Took a bit of screwing around to finally get it up and running, but works great. I now have a page that uses soap to grab all of the column contents from my custom list, it populates a dropdown menu that I made with js, and the links populated withing the dropdown open a dialog window populated with the particular information from that list. Looks great, and the great news is that the guys I work with are happy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the sharepoint javascript api and the modal dialog framework for opening your publishing page with your CEWP:

```
var options = {
   url: "/path/to/my/page.aspx",
   width: 800,
   height: 600,
   allowMaximize: false
};
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

EDIT (after question EDIT): Since you work in SP 2007 you can use just [a popup](http://sharepointkunskap.wordpress.com/2012/02/28/javascript-passing-arguments-from-popup-to-main-window/) (like people editor):

```
var wnd = window.open('/path/to/my/page.aspx', '_blank', 'width=750, height=400, location=no, resizable=1, menubar=0, scrollbars=0');
```

Comment: Thanks Anatoly (again)... Problem is, I'm working in 2007, and from what I've read, this functionality is only in 2010?

Comment: Allright. You are right. Modal Dialogs are only in 2010. Maybe [you can use just a popup](http://sharepointkunskap.wordpress.com/2012/02/28/javascript-passing-arguments-from-popup-to-main-window/)?